KafkIO: unable to create new "old" versions of schema in schema registry, no error
I am creating a new schema in KafkIO and I am unable to create new schemas sometimes. Simplest example, let's say I create a simple schema, version 1:
Create simple schema
Then I create a new schema by adding a field, version 2:
Add new field, create new version of schema
Then if I remove that new field for some reason, and try to create a new schema, I get this "success" message but it still refers to version "2", and there's still just two schemas, not three:
Remove that new field
KafkIO shows just two schemas, not three
It's probably because the "new" schema is a duplicate of an old one, but this seems like a bug.
